# nginx or apache how to serve content from /subfolder no matter what url you are at

Tags: apache, angular, nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I have an frontend app, written in Angular, hosted at http://localhost/subfolder/myapp

When I go to the app, it redirects to route1, the url appears as:
http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/route1

But when I refresh the browser, I get 404 not found error.  I think that's because there is no physical index.html in /subfolder/myapp/route1 and /subfolder/myapp/route1 is not a physical folder.

So I wrote a rewrite rule

```
rewrite ^/subfolder/myapp/.+$ /subfolder/myapp last;
```

But since when I go to http://localhost/subfolder/myapp I am redirected to http://localhost/subfolder/myapp/route1, and the rule is redirecting me back to http://localhost/subfolder/myapp, I am in an infinite redirect state (too many redirect problem)

What can I do in nginx to solve my problem?  Or what about Apache?

Comment: I am very close.  I get something working by doing this `try_files $uri /subfolder/myapp/index.html;`  But what I really want is `try_files /subfolder/myapp/* /subfolder/myapp/index.html;` and `try_files /subfolder2/myapp/* /subfolder2/myapp/index.html;`

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out:

```
    location /subfolder/myapp/ {
        try_files $uri /subfolder/myapp/index.html;
    }

    location /subfolder2/myapp/ {
        try_files $uri /subfolder2/myapp/index.html;
    }
```